# testing for file existence bash

Tags: bash, unix

I've read some other questions, and I feel like i'm doing exactly as everybody else is, but I just can't find the files.

```
file="~/.todo/$1.task"
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "Error. Task ~/.todo/$1.task not found."
    ls ~/.todo/
    exit 1
fi
```

This is inside of a function when del gets called....so with this command, here's the output:

```
$ ./todo.sh del 19
Error. ~/.todo/19.task not found.
10.task  13.task  16.task  1.task  6.task  9.task     tododatesorted
11.task  14.task  18.task  3.task  7.task  taskno
12.task  15.task  19.task  4.task  8.task  tododates
```

How come it says it doesn't exist when really it does? I've tried -e and -f flags although I don't fully understand the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The The difference is in pathname expansion. When you have `~` unquoted, the shell expands it to your home directory. But when it's within quotation marks, as you have it, it does not get expanded. E.g.

```
$ file="~"; echo $file
~
$ file=~; echo $file
/Users/kevin
```

You can fix your script in one of two ways:

1. Drop the quotation marks: `file=~/.todo/$1.task`. In the case of variable assignment like this, whitespace in `$1` won't break the command, but you can quote just the `$1` if you want.
2. Use `$HOME` instead: `file="$HOME/.todo/$1.task"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think tilde expansion is happening when you check `"$file"`.  So the filename
it's looking for still has the tilde character in it, rather than expanding to the
home directory.

Comment: Indeed. But the tilde expansion does happen if you remove the quotes arround $file.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can do this:

```sh
unexpanded_file="~/example.txt"
file="${unexpanded_file/#\~/$HOME}"
```

This should replace ~ with $HOME

Answer (score -4):

Try to get rid of the ';' after the ]...I'm not sure, I can't try it.

Comment: that's just the syntax for putting multiple things on one line.